# How do I update my prompt to show current git branch on linux?

Tags: linux, git, bash, github

I am developing a bash script that adds current branch onto my Terminal prompt and shows information about the most recent commit in this folder whenever I cd into a folder that is a git repository in the terminal

Problem is that whenever I switch branches with `git checkout` within that repository folder the prompt does not update the current branch 
this is my bash code located on my `.bashrc` file

```
cd() {
  builtin cd "$@"
  local status=$?
  [ $status -eq 0 ] && PS1="[\e[0;32m${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\w\e[m]\e[0;35m$(parse_git_branch)\e[m \n$ "
  if [ -d .git ]; then
        echo -e "\nMost Recent Commit"
        git show --summary;

  fi
  return $status
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As documented in the [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Bash) you need the `git-prompt.sh` file (which should be installed as part of Git) and then in your `.bashrc` do something like:

```
. /usr/share/git-core/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
export PS1='\w$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")\$ '
```

Answer (score 2):

On most linux distros you can get the branch by doing.

```
echo $(__git_ps1)
(develop)
```

If __git_ps1 unavailable, you have to source git-sh-prompt first. It may be git-prompt.sh on other distros.

```
source /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt
```

Comment: Only after sourcing `git-prompt.sh`

Comment: @JonathanWakely I don't have that file on ubuntu, but I've updated my answer with the correct file to source, if your distro haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

you have to change you ~/.bashrc and export the PS1 environment variable.

Here is an example of a ~/.bashrc:

```
# settings for this script
MY_DOMAIN=$(hostname -f | sed -e "s/^[^.]*\.//")
MY_FQDN=$(hostname -f)
MY_TTY=$(tty| cut -f3- -d/)
MY_USER=$(whoami)

MY_ROT="\033[31m"
MY_GRUEN="\033[32m"
MY_GELB="\033[33m"
MY_BLAU="\033[34m"
MY_LILA="\033[35m"
MY_CYAN="\033[36m"
MY_WEISS="\033[37m"
MY_FETT="\033[1m"
MY_NORMAL="\033[2m"
MY_RESET="\033[0m"

# user color
MY_U="$MY_BLAU"
case $MY_USER in
  developer)
    MY_U="$MY_GRUEN"
    ;;
  root)
    MY_U="$MY_ROT"
    ;;
esac
[ $(id -u) -eq 0 ] && MY_U="$MY_U$MY_FETT"
MY_U="\[$MY_U\]"

# host color
MY_H="$MY_ROT"
MY_H="\[$MY_H\]"

# working directory color
MY_W="\[$MY_CYAN\]"

# tty color
MY_T="\[$MY_BLAU$MY_FETT\]"

MY_R="\[$MY_RESET\]"
MY_G="\[$MY_GELB\]"
MY_GF="\[$MY_GELB$MY_FETT\]"
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=1
GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE=1
GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM=verbose
export PS1="$MY_U\u$MY_R$MY_G@$MY_R$MY_H\h$MY_R$MY_G($MY_R$MY_T$MY_TTY \t$MY_R$MY_G):$MY_R$MY_W\w$MY_R\$(__git_ps1 \"$MY_GF:$MY_R \[$MY_ROT\](%s)$MY_R \")$MY_GF\$$MY_R "
```

which renders this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this one in your ~/.bash_profile file... Dynamically update your prompt with current git branch. Leave a git directory space and get a different prompt.

```
promptFunc() {

    branch=$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '^*' | colrm 1 2)
    if [ ! $branch ]; then
        PS1=${PWD}"$ "
    else
        PS1="\W: "${branch}"-> "
    fi
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND="promptFunc"
```